# How to check the storyboard whether this is begin or not?

Tags: wpf, storyboard, code-behind

I need to know whether the `Storyboard` is begun or not. If it is begun, I need to stop, otherwise I no need to stop. Both begin and stop will be done in code behind.

Currently I've done this:

```
if (parameter != null && parameter is System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard)
{
    if (!(bool)value)
    {
        (parameter as System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard).Begin();
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        (parameter as System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard).Stop();
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

I have faced the binding error:

> System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6 : Unable to perform action
>   because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for
>   interactive control.; Action='Stop';
>   Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   Storyboard.HashCode='7861304';
>   Storyboard.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   TargetElement='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   TargetElement.HashCode='7861304';
>   TargetElement.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'

Can anyone share how to stop the storyboard once its begun?

Comment: Is this a part of a converter? What is `value`? Show some more code. Also read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741997%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: value is boolean, yes its a converter. what i want is need to skip the stop operation if it is called before Begin (). please help me.

Comment: I need to stop the storyboard once it is start only, otherwise i need to skip the Stop operation. any suggestion on this ?